# как упаковать и распаковать ARJ архивы в JAVA

Tags: java, архивация

Как упаковать и распаковать несколько текстовых файлов в ARJ архив и наоборот на JAVA. В проекте не рекомендуется использование ARJ архиваторов .

Comment: Может еще и сторонние библиотеки нельзя?

Comment: это, извините, некрофилия какая-то. Последний раз arj-архив я видел лет 15 назад наверное. А так то http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/examples.html и вот http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/ , но там только расжатие емнип